# Is there a way to prove the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem without the use of cofactors, adjoints, etc?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof, cayley-hamilton

> Is there a way to prove the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem without the use of cofactors, adjoints, etc?

Like is there another way to natural prove general matrix will satisfy its own characteristic polynomial?

Comment: This is an interesting question.

Comment: Axler's book does this. https://linear.axler.net/

Comment: [Howard Straubing, *A combinatorial proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(83)90164-4).

Comment: You can treat the theorem as a universal polynomial identity, which allows you to reduce the proof the case of diagonalizable matrices over $\mathbf C$, where the calculation is very simple. See Theorem 3.4 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf.

Comment: Yes. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ maps every eigenvector to $0$, so you get $p(A)=0$ directly for diagonalizable matrices because eigenvectors form a basis. In general, approximate $A$ by diagonalizable matrices and note that their polynomials converge to its in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

If done in the right way, one can simply substitute $A$ for $x$ in $\rm{det}(xI-A)=0$.  Look at my question [On the Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696442/403337)