# Cayley Hamilton proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, cayley-hamilton

I'm currently studying Cayley-Hamilton proof, but I think I'm missing something massive.

The theorem states that an endomorphism $\phi$ cancels its characteristic polynomial. I don't understand why the proof is not trivial.

Let $A$ be a matrix of $\phi$ in a basis $\mathcal{B}$. We know that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the same as $\phi$ no matter which basis of the vector space we take.
Then,
$$P_A(A)=\det(A-AI)=\det(A-A)=0$$

So the proof should be trivial, I don't understand where my error is.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141648/81360). I find the second answer from the top particularly convincing.

Comment: There is a formalism which allows the substitution to be made and constitute a proof. If I recall correctly, it is in Rings and Ideals (Carus Mathematical Monographs, No 8) (Carus Monograph) Textbook Binding – June 1, 1948
by Neal H McCoy (Author).

Comment: It should be $\lambda I$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar, not a matrix. You can't make the substitution you've done of $A$ for $\lambda$ in this calculation as you have.